# Browserify cannot find required script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, browserify

I am building a project with npm and Browserify, something I wrote using ReactJS. It is divided into a hierarchy of scripts, where the imported script that is executed first must import another script to run.
In my project the hierarchy is: index.js > Fahter > Group > Event . The build calls index.js, which calls Group, which in turn calls Event. Group and Event are React classes.

But the build does not recognize Group at all: it is not defined. The console.log reveals it to be recognized as a function exports(). What should I do to make it recognize as a React class?

Event:

```
var React = require('react');
var RealNumberInput = React.createClass ({
/*stuff*/
});
var NumberInput = React.createClass ({
/*stuff*/
});
module.exports = React.createClass ({
/*stuff*/
});
```

Group:

```
var React = require('react');
var Event = require("./Event.js");
var Operator = React.createClass({
/*stuff*/
});
module.exports = React.createClass ({
/*stuff*/
});
```

Father:

```
var Group = require("./Group.js");
var Event = require("./Event.js");
module.exports = React.createClass ({
/*stuff*/
});
```

index.js:

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var React = require('react');
var Father = require('./Father.js');
var Group = require('./Group.js');
var Event = require('./Event.js');

ReactDOM.render ( <Father />, document.getElementById('here') )
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @AndyRay ok did it

Comment: There is no `var React = require('react');` in `Father.js`

Comment: `But the build does not recognize Group at all: it is not defined` can you clarify what this means? Is there an error that browserify is giving you? is there a runtime error? if there is an error, can you add it?

Comment: More then likely you have one or more of the following happening => misspelled file names or variables, incorrect locations, a race condition or missing code.